# PostgreSQL: Not fully alphanumeric, Not fully in capital letters, Length different than 18

Tags: sql, postgresql, iban

could you please help me writing the script which would bring an output for these requirements??

Select IBANs which are:

- Not fully alphanumeric
- Not fully in capital letters
- Length different than 18

My current query:

```sql
Select *
FROM Table
WHERE ibanaccount NOT LIKE '%[A-Z0-9]%' 
AND length(ibanaccount)<>18 
AND UPPER(ibanaccount) = 'AAbbCC';
```

Comment: Your check doesn't make sense, _"The IBAN number consists of a two-letter country code, followed by two check digits, and up to thirty-five alphanumeric characters."_ (from https://www.investopedia.com/terms/i/iban.asp). You seem to assume some country specific length.

Comment: The SQL `LIKE` operator does not support regular expressions

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What does "Not fully alphanumeric" means? All IBANs start with 2 letters followed by 2 digits so in this sense they are all alphanumeric.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a regular expressions here:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE ibnaccount ~* '[^A-Z0-9]' AND  -- matches non alphanumeric character
      LENGTH(ibanaccount) <> 18 AND  -- length is not 18
      ibnaccount ~ '[^A-Z]';         -- at least one non uppercase letter
```